# typedef and variable names

Tags: c, variables, scope, declaration, typedef

Ignoring why I would want to do this, just trying to understand what is happening here:
This code compiles:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef char byte;

int main (void) 
{
    byte var_byte;
    int byte = 10;

    printf("\n Test program: %d\n", byte);
}
```

But, if I change the order in which the variables are declared, it does not compile.

This DOES NOT COMPILE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef char byte;

int main (void)
{
    int byte = 10;
    byte var_byte;

    printf("\n Test program: %d\n", byte);
}
```

Compiler error:

```
b.c:7:8: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘var_byte’
   byte var_byte;
        ^~~~~~~~
```

Could someone please explain why order matters?

Comment: Doesn't compile with what error?

Comment: And in the second one, you create a variable with the same name as the type, then try to use the type below it. You're probably shadowing the typedef with the variable name.

Comment: You might care to observe that: `int main (void) 
{ typedef char byte;
    byte var_byte;
    int byte = 10;
    printf("\n Test program: %d\n", byte);
}` does not compile because the type name `byte` cannot be changed in the scope of `main()` — it can only be changed in an inner scope.

Comment: It has been stated, many times, that it is very poor programming practice to use the same name for both a typedef name  for a variable name.  Usually, the compiler can distinguish the difference, but not always.  The OP has found one of the 'not always' instances

Answer (score 8):

In this program

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef char byte;

int main (void)
{
    int byte = 10;
    byte var_byte;

    printf("\n Test program: %d\n", byte);
}
```

the name of the variable `byte` hides the name of the typedef.

From the C Standard (6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers)

> 4. ... If an identifier designates two different entities in the same name space, the scopes might overlap. If so, the scope of one entity
>      (the inner scope) will end strictly before the scope of the other
>      entity (the outer scope). **Within the inner scope, the identifier
>      designates the entity declared in the inner scope; the entity declared
>      in the outer scope is hidden (and not visible) within the inner
>      scope.**

Pay attention to that the name of an identifier and a typedef name belong to the same name space.

The typedef name is declared in the global scope (file scope) while the name of the variable is declared in the inner block scope and the name of the variable hides the name declared in the global scope.

Consider this program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef char byte;

void f( void );

int main (void)
{
    int byte = 10;

    printf("\n Test program: %d\n", byte);

    f();
}

void f( void )
{
    byte c = 'A';
    printf( "%c\n", c );
}
```

Within the block scope of the function `main` (the inner scope relative to the file scope) the name of the typedef is hidden by the declaration of the variable with the same name.

However inside the block scope of the function `f` the name declared in the typedef is visible because neither other declaration in the block scope of the function hides the name declared in the typedef.

Here is a more interesting program that deals with the point of declaration (it is a C++ term)

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t byte = 255;

int main(void) 
{
    typedef int byte[byte];

    {
        byte byte;

        printf( "sizeof( byte ) = %zu\n", sizeof( byte ) );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
sizeof( byte ) = 1020
```

Here is in the file scope there is declared variable with the name `byte`

```
size_t byte = 255;
```

In the outer block scope of the function `main` there is introduced typedef name `byte`.

```
typedef int byte[byte];
```

It hides the previously declared name `byte` after declaration of the declarator. That is in this typedef

```
    typedef int byte[byte];
```

the name `byte` in the square braces corresponds to the global name `byte`.

Then in the inner block scope there is declared an array with the same name  `byte` that hides the typedef name.

```
byte byte;
```

Pay attention to that in the expression

```
sizeof( byte )
```

there is used the name of the array not the typedef name.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit here:** (misunderstand of the question)

When you declare a variable in C it does not look for `typedef` structures to see if a structure named the same with the variable. On the first code,

```
byte var_byte;
```

this line of code comes before the declaration of the variable `int byte`. The computer will look for the most recent reference of the word byte as it was the structure name here.

On the second one the the variable `int byte` does not return an error because you can still create variables with the same structure type name in C. But after you do so you can't create new structures to that structure as the computer will think that it is referring to the variable name and not the the structure type as the variable was declared **most recently**

Comment: This does not (at least not clearly) explain why the order matters.

Comment: @Schwifty McSchwifulface  how is it now?